# On an interface, define a specific field name with one type, and generic type for all the rest

Tags: typescript

In Typescript (5.0+), how can I achieve the following:

```
export interface MyFirstInterface {
  fieldCanOnlyBeString: string,
  fieldCanOnlyBeNumber: number,
  [unknownFieldName:string]: MyCustomInterface
}
```

Whenever I declare a variable with the `MyFirstInterface` type, I would like one field to be a number, one is a string and the rest be `MyCustomInterface`

How can I declare this in TS, given the classic `[key:string]: string` would mean *every* string key-type must be a string type?

What is the correct way to realise the idea of "specific field names have a specific type, all the other fields must be this other type" in Typescript?

I have tried with a couple of generics with various types, unions, never's etc... but no other solutions really answered my problem in straightforward manner.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no great solution here, only various workarounds.  See the linked q/a for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an intersection :

```
declare type MyCustomInterface = {};

export type MyType = {
  fieldCanOnlyBeString: string,
  fieldCanOnlyBeNumber: number,
} & {[unknownFieldName:string]: MyCustomInterface}


const foo:MyType = {fieldCanOnlyBeNumber:3, fieldCanOnlyBeString: 'test', foo: 'im good'}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAXAngBwQWWQYQK4GdEB7AWwEkA7REGAMyjAQF54BvAXwG4AobkAD1REYiJGkzIAKuPgtW3ePFoBLEBGDYoFAPIUIyAEIgAyohjKKAcwBc8QuasAaBUtXrNOvYZAA5XCQAjGlsKfyCYZ3Z4ADJFVgBtXAoAawoiAHcKADE3YB8oEhBrewtLAF1bLDxCUkpqOgYQdl5uMCIKQiUiImssaXRZNhU1DS1dfSM-QOCAZkdXEY9x71MHG3gAcmpCDfnabtsN5RJ4S27gDfYgA)

Comment: And why is this intersection non-empty? To me, intersection of "all keys are of type X and values are of type Y" with "key K has value of type Z which is not a subtype of Y" should be strictly null set. Is it one more place where typescript invents is own typing theory that does not match the math behind?

Comment: @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike that's because `string & {}` is not `never` (unlike e.g. `string & number`)

Comment: @Dimava ough. Because `{}` is a subtype of string here. So this will die for non-blank interface, right?

Comment: Oh, yes, it does fail for (almost?) all interfaces but a trivial one.

Comment: @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike for non-partial ones unless you typecast

Comment: Empty object types are not good examples; I'd always recommend adding some structure even for toy code, otherwise you will accidentally recommend approaches that don't actually work.  Intersections like this work fairly well for *consuming* a value of the desired type, but are not good for *producing* such a value.